# sort alphabetically whole word in first array position

Tags: perl

I have a file with values separated by pipe `|`

#### input:

```
car tree alfa young|salt brick|23223|
emilia jack albert| way to go|56566|
```

I'm trying to sort first column alphabetically and write sorted file out.

#### result:

```
alfa car tree young|salt brick|23223|
albert emilia jack| way to go|56566|
```

What I have tried:
can sort first array position but cant write out all file content.

```
 $filename = 'test.dat';
 open (INPUT,"$filename");
 open (OUTPUT,">out.dat");

 while (<INPUT>)
 {
   @array = split('\|');
   @arr = split(' ',$array[0]);
   $,=" ";
   print OUTPUT sort @arr,"\n";
  }
   close (INPUT);
   close (OUTPUT);
```

sorts everything in each line.

```
 $filename = 'test.dat';
 open (INPUT,"$filename");
 open (OUTPUT,">out.dat");

 while (<INPUT>)
 {
   @arr = split(' ');
   $,=" ";
   print OUTPUT sort @arr,"\n";
  }
   close (INPUT);
   close (OUTPUT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your programs will be far more flexible if you move away from the idea of hard-coding file names in your code. It's a much better idea to read from `STDIN` and write to `STDOUT` whenever possible. That's what this code does.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  # Split the record into the first field (the one we want to sort)
  # and everything else.
  my ($first, $rest) = split /\|/, $_, 2;

  # Split the first record into words
  my @words = split /\s+/, $first;

  # Sort @words and then join the line back together and print it.
  print join(' ', sort @words), "|$rest";
}
```

If we store this program in a file called `reorder`, we can then run it from a command-line prompt like this:

```
$ ./reorder < test.dat > out.dat
```

We avoid having to open any filehandles (the operating system does it for us) and we don't need to change the program if the filenames ever change.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe 's/^([^|]+)/@a = sort split ' ', $1; "@a";/e' myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

After you've `split` the line into an array

```
my @ary = split '\|';
```

you need to `split` the first element, `sort` the list, and `join` it back

```
my $first = join ' ', sort split ' ', shift @ary;
```

where `shift` removes (and returns) the first element.

Then build the string back

```
my $new_string = join '|', $first, @ary;
```

This can be done without temporary variables. The last two steps can be done in one statement, and all of it right in a `print` statement.

Comments

- Please always start your programs with `use warnings;` and `use strict;`
- Use three-argument form of `open`

  ```
  open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
  ```

  and so use *lexical filehandles* (`$fh`), not bareword (typeglobs, `FH`).
- Don't quote things that don't *need to* be quoted -- even errors can result!  See [What's wrong with always quoting (perlfaq4)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What%27s-wrong-with-always-quoting-%22%24vars%22%3f), for instance.  Thanks to [Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-%C3%9Cn%C3%BCr) for the comment.

---

You can also do it with a regex

```
$line =~ s/(.*?)\|/join(" ", sort split " ", $1).q(|)/e;
```

This captures the first field (up to the pipe), and runs the above code on it, courtesy of `/e` modifier which makes replacement part be evaluated as code.

We needed to also match the pipe and then put it back.  This can be avoided using [lookahead](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

```
$line =~ s/(.*?)(?=\|)/join(' ', sort split ' ', $1)/e;
```

which only asserts that the pattern inside `(?=...)` is there, without consuming it.

Comment: Ty for all the step by step explanation

Comment: @SinanÜnür  Thank you, a very good point which need be made.  Added as a bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Your first bit of code is so very close to being right. You're only outputting the first column though - you need to print out the contents of `@array`. If you replace the first element of `@array` with the sorted results, then you can just write it out like this.

```
@array = split('\|');
$array[0] = join(" ",sort split(' ',$array[0]));
print OUTPUT join("|",@array),"\n";
```